# Ninject register per request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

My ASP.NET MVC 3 application uses Ninject and Ninject ASP.NET MVC 3 integration. I have overloaded CreateKernel method.

Now I need to set some dependencies per query in this way:

```
if (Language == Language.English)
  //register English language implementations
else if (Language == Language.Russian)
  //register Russain language implementations
```

I thougt some of Request-specific methods of Global_asax would be a nice place for and tried to access some of NinjectHttpApplicaton properties to register dependencies per request. I accessed Kernel and got obsolete warning "Don't use Ninject as Service locator". What am I doing wrong? How to do it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the implementation based on some condition like language you should use conditional bindings. E.g. `Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().When(ctx => Language == Language.English)`

Comment: You are right, I can register my dependencies this way at CreateKernel. But I would prefer to register them InRequestScope instead of creating custom lambda-scope

Comment: A condition is not a scope. It just defines when a binding applies. You can still use InRequestScope

Comment: I understand. But I want to calculate (once) language (or any other query-specific condition) dynamically and setup all dependencies for it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you are the developer of this library first :) Why isn't it a good practice to register dependencies directly through Kernel property? In my case it looks pretty reasonable, doesn't it?

Comment: If you register the bindings for every request you end up with thousands of bindings for the same thing after a short time and run into a OutOfMemoryException. But most likely the second request will already fail as there are two unconditional bindings for the same thing. The standard way is to register all required bindings at application start up and use them for the complete application lifecycle.

Comment: But how can I get OutOfMemoryException if I register them per request. Won't they be cleared after request is finished?

Comment: The scope does not tell how long the binding exists but how long the objects created by this binding exist.